# Can't Install ros-hydro-desktop-full from USB stick

Tags: usb, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Trying to setup a USB stick with ROS for a student.  Get to the following command and I get this error:

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-desktop-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ros-hydro-desktop-full : Depends: ros-hydro-desktop but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-hydro-mobile but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-hydro-perception but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-hydro-simulators but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$

Am using UBUNTU 12.04 Live and UNETBOOTIN loader.

Was wondering how to proceed to fix it?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/153871/can%27t-install-ros-hydro-desktop-full-from-usb-stick/) by [billtecteacher](https://answers.ros.org/users/9406/billtecteacher/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2014-04-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Never mind just answered my own comment shoud be sudo apt-get install aptitude not installed by default on 12.04

---

Originally posted by [billtecteacher](https://answers.ros.org/users/9406/billtecteacher/) with karma: 101 on 2014-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is the package manager complaining that it can't find the dependencies for ROS for some reason.

aptitude is better at resolving these things sometimes; try running:

```
sudo aptitude install ros-hydro-desktop-full
```

But be careful to read the solutions that it proposes; sometimes they can involve removing or downgrading other packages that you have installed, which may not be what you want.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-04-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [billtecteacher](https://answers.ros.org/users/9406/billtecteacher/) on 2014-04-16**:
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo aptitude install ros-hydro-desktop-full
sudo: aptitude: command not found
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get aptitude
E: Invalid operation aptitude
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$

How does one get aptitude on to system?

**Comment by [billtecteacher](https://answers.ros.org/users/9406/billtecteacher/) on 2014-04-16**:
aptitude was not able to resolve dependencies

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-04-16**:
I suspect aptitude gave you different errors; can you add those to your question?

**Comment by [billtecteacher](https://answers.ros.org/users/9406/billtecteacher/) on 2014-04-17**:
Just started today looking into debian packages.  There is a lot to the package system that I always took for granted because it worked for me.  There are 300 + packages not getting installed including collida and on down the list.  If I put a more to see the first part of the command I get the following and it returns to prompt after this instead of sending a ton of messages to the screen:

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo aptitude install ros-hydro-desktop-full | more
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Reading extended state information...
Initializing package states...
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$

**Comment by [billtecteacher](https://answers.ros.org/users/9406/billtecteacher/) on 2014-04-17**:
The lock file in last post for some reason was left with a permission which killed the script. I can fix the lock permission and it goes back to error with list of 300+ packages not installed.  I think I can learn more myself diving into aptitude command thanks to you.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-04-17**:
Yeah, there's quite a bit to the package manager. It may be worth confirming that you have the `restricted`, `universe` and `multiverse` repositories enabled.